# jsonResponse from api success but doesn't work

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I'm using `.then(jsonResponse =>` after a fetch function, i stringfied it and logged it into the console to see if the api returns the confirmation key as "success", even though it returns as success the statement:

```
if (jsonResponse.confirmation === "success") {
          this.props.navigation.navigate("main");
    }
```

Is not working, it doesn't navigate to the 'main' screen, does anyone know how to fix this? I've been searching the forum for an answer but couldn't find, here's how the code is organized:

```
  register() {
    fetch(config.baseUrl + "signup", {
      method: "POST",
      headers: {
        Accept: "application/json",
        "Content-Type": "application/json"
      },
      body: JSON.stringify(this.state.credenciais)
    }) //all of this works, since it connects to the api and registers the user with its credentials
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(jsonResponse => {
        console.log(JSON.stringify(jsonResponse)) //this returns as success
        console.log(response) // returns as undefined
        if (jsonResponse.confirmation === "success") {
          this.props.navigation.navigate("main");
        } else {
          throw new Error({
            message: "Algo ocorreu de errado, por favor tente novamente"
          });
        }
      })
      .catch(err => {
        console.log(err.message);
      });
  }
```

I commented the parts where I couldn't figure it out, and in the api I have as the route:

```
 router.post("/signup", function(req, res) {
    console.log(req.body);
    turbo
      .createUser(req.body)
      .then(data => {
        res.json({
          confirmation: "success",
          data: data
        });
      })
      .catch(err => {
        res.json({
          confirmation: "fail",
          message: err.message
        });
      });
  });
```

As you can see, I have confirmation: success if everything goes right, the code above works and registers the user but doesn't navigate to the 'main' screen, does anyone know what is wrong with my code?

Edit: As asked below here's the console.log(JSON.stringify(jsonResponse))

> {"confirmation":"success","data":{"firstName":"","lastName":"","email":"testestes@aol.com","username":"","bio":"","image":"","timestamp":"2018-11-03T16:16:00.855Z","stripe":{},"schema":"user","id":"5bddc9c050edeb001431cb2e"}}

Also, the register() is called in a TouchableOpacity:

```
 <TouchableOpacity
          onPress={() => {
            this.register();
          }}
        >
```

Comment: You might need to bind the register method in order to use "this". Can you debug and inspect if this, props, and navigation values are correct?

Comment: Okay, so i did some console.log in some values, it seems that it's entering the IF statement but it crashes as it says "user" is undefined

Comment: Obviously response will be undefined since in `.then` where you console log the value doesn't know what `response` is. As Faruk said you have to bind the register function to use `this`. However if you have already bind it elsewhere, you have to provide what is your console log output of the `console.log(JSON.stringify(jsonResponse)) ` here to get more help.

Comment: @SamithaNanayakkara Sorry, i totally forgot about that, just added it.

Comment: I cannot find any problem there. Did this throw the error you have defined in else? Or did you try to console log inside if condition to check whether this pass to if condition?

Comment: @SamithaNanayakkara it didn't it passes the user settings and everything, enters the if statement (used console.log to check that) and says Cannot read property 'user' of undefined

Comment: I'm apologizing in advance as it's gonna be rude, as this same question was asked by you earlier. I'm rude because even after telling you how to debug, you still doing same mistake and still coding without going through basics and wasting other people time. Are you so dumb to notice is `console.log(JSON.stringify(jsonResponse))` is `success` then how come its property will have success? like `a='success'` and then asking why `a.data` is not `'success'`. Also about `console.log(response) // returns as undefined` do you know anything about scoping? variable scoping?

Comment: Use `request.js` in place of `fetch` as most developer uses `request` and will be able to tell what's going on. what does `response.json()` returns?

Comment: @NAVIN i responded you in that other thread, this is different. Okay, so i realized that was not causing the problem, what's causing the problem, it was a params that i was passing in a total different file that wasn't defined, thus why "user not defined"